# Usage of saxon:recognize-binary

Tags: xslt, binary, saxon

When I try to run this XSLT style sheet (adapted from http://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/201001/msg00361.html) with Saxon 9.1.0.8 or Saxon-HE 9.5.1.3J, I get an empty output file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output saxon:recognize-binary="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <?hex 07?>
    <xsl:processing-instruction name="hex" select="'07'"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From the [Saxon documentation](http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/extensions/output-extras/recognize-binary.html) and the message mentioned above, I would have expected that the output is a string containing one (or two) `^G` characters.  Why did I not get any output at all?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Currently it is unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom serialization requires Saxon-PE (or EE).

You should've gotten an error similar to this:

> Transformation failed: Requested feature (custom serialization
>   {http://saxon.sf.net/}recognize-binary) requires Saxon-PE

http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensions

Comment: More specifically, with 9.3.0.5 I get "Error at xsl:output on line 3 column 59 of test.xsl:
  XTSE0020: Serialization parameter {{http://saxon.sf.net/}recogniz...} is not available in Saxon-HE
Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected."

Comment: For some reason I am not getting the error message. I expected the attribute to be available, because on other attributes (e.g. for `saxon:ptree`), the documentation explicitly states that Saxon-EE and/or Saxon-PE is required.  Not so for `saxon:recognize-binary` - perhaps that is an oversight.

Comment: @user1010997 - I think any attributes or extension functions in the saxon namespace require PE/EE. I don't have anything to confirm that though.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with Saxon-EE 9.3.0.5 and it works.

Note that you need the xsl:processing-instruction form. Literal PIs in a stylesheet are stripped out, they do not cause processing instructions to be sent to the output.